# Python: Trying to create a dictionary from a Series gives Key Error 0

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series **series1**

```
Currency
Rupees   45.6
dtype: float64
```

I want to create a dataframe from this series and hence am using a dictionary as an intermediate step since using this code

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Currency': series1.index[0], 'Amount': series1[0]})
```

gave me this **ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index**

The code for the dictionary that I am using is this-

```
dct = {'Currency': series1.index[0], 'Amount': series1[0]}
dct = {k:[v] for k,v in dct.items()}  
df = pd.DataFrame(dct)
```

This works for individual instances but when I am putting this code in a loop and trying to append the resulting dataframe repeatedly, then it is throwing an error for the line where the dictionary is getting defined - **KeyError: 0**

Desired Output will be like

```
    Currency    Amount
0   Rupees       45.6
1   Dollar       0.70
```

Comment: How looks your loop? Can you add to question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a series to a dictionary, you can simply use the `to_dict` method:

```
print(series1.to_dict())
```

gives as expected:

```
{'Rupees': 45.6}
```

Your problem is that `series1[x]` look for `x` in the index of the `Series`. You have to use `iloc` if you want *positional indices*:

```
dct = {'Currency': series1.index[0], 'Amount': series1.iloc[0]}
```

Or you could directly build the dataframe from the expected sequences:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Currency': series1.index, 'Amount': series1.to_list()},
                  index = range(len(series1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC why not use:

```
df = series1.reset_index(name='Amount')
```

But it depends what need this solution, maybe exist some better way.